# HTTP Basic Auth on Twisted-Klein server

Tags: python, flask, twisted, werkzeug

I am using `Twisted-Klein` as a server. Here is a simple example:

```
from klein import Klein


app = Klein()


@app.route('/health', methods=['GET'])
def health_check(request):
    return ''


@app.route('/query/<path:expression>', methods=['GET'])
def query(request, expression):
    return 'Expression: {0}'.format(expression)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

How can I add HTTP Basic Auth to `query` API endpoint? With Flask, this is simple: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/

But I fail to find any examples of how to do this on Twisted-Klein server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted itself has [support for HTTP basic (and digest) authentication](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/http-auth.html), factored as a resource *wrapper* that can be applied to any other resource.

Your klein example doesn't demonstrate it, but klein can (must, really) [create a resource from your app](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/2-twistdtap.html) in order to use Twisted's web server.

You can combine them something like:

```
import attr
from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.cred.portal import IRealm
from twisted.internet.defer import succeed
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.web.resource import IResource
from twisted.web.guard import HTTPAuthSessionWrapper, BasicCredentialFactory
from klein import Klein

app = Klein()
# ... define your klein app

@implementer(IRealm)
@attr.s
class TrivialRealm(object):
    resource = attr.ib()

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        # You could have some more complicated logic here, but ...
        return succeed((IResource, self.resource, lambda: None))

def resource():
    realm = TrivialRealm(resource=app.resource())
    portal = Portal(realm, [<some credentials checkers>])
    credentialFactory = BasicCredentialFactory(b"http auth realm")
    return HTTPAuthSessionWrapper(portal, [credentialFactory])
```

You can run this according to [the klein docs for using `twistd web`](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/2-twistdtap.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this tommorow.

Comment: When I try to run the server with `twistd`, I receive the following error: `no module named 'application'`. Do I have to create `setup.py` file, and how? Maybe it's better if I open another SO question about this.

Comment: What twistd command line did you use?  An error about "application" kind of sounds like you're trying to use its WSGI feature but the klein docs I linked to suggest the `--class` parameter, not WSGI.

Comment: I'm using `twistd -n web --class=application.resource`, and my file is named `application.py`

Comment: Did you put the directory containing application.py in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I did not. That fixed it! One more question, how can I make simple user/pass auth, I have user/pass stored in yaml file which I would like to use for http auth. I can see that in examples there is FilePasswordDB() usage, but can't find examples of how to auth user if I have user/pass as pair of simple strings?

Comment: I made it work with `FilePasswordDB()`. Also, can I disable auth for specific APIs?

Comment: twisted.web.guard works by protecting entire branches of the URL hierarchy.  You don't have to wrap / though.  You could put it at /authenticated and have /anonymous be available without any authentication.  You can also explicitly allow anonymous access with an anonymous checker and some anonymous support in the realm (where I put the "more complicated logic here" comment.  Read the twisted cred docs if you haven't already.